# We can't retrieve API reports for new accounts in application (error 294)

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

When adding a new account to our application and try to download its advertising data we get:

> "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.."

and in the report files we see:

```
"{"error":
   {"message":"(#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management and an application that is whitelisted to access the Ads API",
  "type":"OAuthException","code":294}}"
```

old accounts are working, but if we delete the app from their settings, and reassigning them - we get the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your application is "[whitelisted](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access)", and enabled with the "manage_ads" extended permission, per the [facebook ads api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview#configure-app).